# Python 3 file input change in binary mode

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

In Python 3, when I opened a text file with mode string 'rb', and then did f.read(), I was taken aback to find the file contents enclosed in single quotes after the character 'b'.

In Python 2 I just get the file contents.

I'm sure this is well known, but I can't find anything about it in the doco.  Could someone point me to it?

Comment: Is http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit adequate?

Comment: Anyone switching from Python 2 to Python 3 should read http://python3porting.com/ . It's not that big. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get "just the file contents" in Python 3 as well. Most likely you can just keep on doing whatever you were doing anyway. Read on for a longer explanation:

The b'' signifies that the result value is a `bytes` string. A `bytes`-string is quite similar to a normal string, but not quite, and is used to handle binary, non-textual data.

Some of the methods on a string that doesn't make sense for binary data is gone, but most are still there. A big difference is that when you get a specific byte from a `bytes` string you get an integer back, while for a normal `str` you get a one-length `str`.

```
>>> b'foo'[1]
111
>>> 'foo'[1]
'o'
```

If you open the file in text mode with the 't' flag you get a `str` back. The Python 3 `str` is what in Python 2 was called `unicode`. It's used to handle textual data.

You convert back and forth between `bytes` and `str` with the `.encode()` and `.decode` methods.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the Python 2 `str` type has been renamed to `bytes` in Python 3, and byte literals use the `b''` prefix. The Python 2 `unicode` type is the new Python 3 `str` type.

To get the Python 3 file behaviour in Python 2, you'd use `io.open()` or `codecs.open()`; Python 3 decodes text files to Unicode *by default*.

What you see is that for *binary* files, Python 3 gives you the *exact same thing* as in Python 2, namely byte strings. What changed then, is that the `repr()` of a byte string is prefixed with `b` and the `print()` function will use the `repr()` representation of any object passed to it *except for unicode values*.

To print your binary data as unicode text with the `print()` function., decode it to unicode first. But then you could perhaps have opened the file as a text file instead anyway.

The `bytes` type has some other improvements to reflect that you are dealing with binary data, not text. Indexing individual bytes or iterating over a `bytes` value gives you `int` values (between 0 and 255) and not characters, for example.

Comment: Beat you with 17 seconds! ;-) Any way, Python 3 `bytes` and Python 2 `str` are not the exact same thing. Just almost. :-)

Comment: Yeah, index access has been improved too.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we need (needed?) to know whether a text file had single-character newlines (0A) or double character newlines (0D0A).

We used to avoid confusion by opening the text file in binary mode, recognising 0D and 0A, and treating other bytes as regular text characters.

One could port such code by finding all binary﷓mode reads and replacing them with a new function oldread() that stripped off the added  material, but it’s a bit painful.

I suppose the Python theologians thought of keeping ‘rb’ as it was, and adding  a new ‘rx’ or something for the new behaviour.  It seems a bit high-handed just to abolish something.

But, there it is, **the question is certainly answered** by a search for ‘rb’ in Lennert’s document.